# Middleman bower and Susy

Tags: bower, middleman, susy-sass

I'm using middleman 3.3.3 with bower to install some js/css packages.
I can make my scss works but middleman can't find where susy framework is. (is inside bower_components).
I'm also using middleman-sprockets.

So my config.rb is like that:

```
activate :sprockets

###
# Page options, layouts, aliases and proxies
###

# Per-page layout changes:
#
# With no layout
# page "/path/to/file.html", layout: false
#
# With alternative layout
# page "/path/to/file.html", layout: :otherlayout
#
# A path which all have the same layout
# with_layout :admin do
#   page "/admin/*"
# end

# Proxy pages (http://middlemanapp.com/basics/dynamic-pages/)
# proxy "/this-page-has-no-template.html", "/template-file.html", locals: {
#  which_fake_page: "Rendering a fake page with a local variable" }

###
# Helpers
###

# Automatic image dimensions on image_tag helper
# activate :automatic_image_sizes

# Reload the browser automatically whenever files change
# activate :livereload

# Methods defined in the helpers block are available in templates
# helpers do
#   def some_helper
#     "Helping"
#   end
# end


ready do
  sprockets.append_path File.join root, 'bower_components'
end

set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'

set :js_dir, 'javascripts'

set :images_dir, 'images'

set :fonts_dir, 'fonts'


# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  # For example, change the Compass output style for deployment
  # activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  activate :minify_javascript

  # Enable cache buster
  # activate :asset_hash

  activate :gzip

  # Use relative URLs
  activate :relative_assets

  # Or use a different image path
  # set :http_prefix, "/Content/images/"
end
```

My file tree is like:

myproject
  - bower_components
    - susy
      - sass
      - lib
      - templates
      - bower.json
    - ...
  - config
  - scripts
  - source
    - stylesheets
       - all.css
       - _setting.scss
    - ...
  - bower.json
  - config.rb
  - ....

all.css

```
/*
 * This file is the same as rails' application.scss
 */

//= require "_settings"
```

_settings.scss

```
// Add all required scss files/folders
@import "susy";
```

The error that i get tell me that it keep going to search "susy" in source/stylesheets.
Any ints?

Answer (score 0):

> Sprockets supports Bower, so you can add your Bower components path directly:
>
> ```
> sprockets.append_path File.join root, 'bower_components'
> ```

http://middlemanapp.com/basics/asset-pipeline/#sprockets-import-path

Comment: tnk for the answer but as you can see from my code, I already try to use this solution and it doesn't work. Now i'm using Grunt but still...

Answer (score 0):

In the `config.rb`

I ve added

```
sass_dir = 'source/stylesheets', 'bower_components'

after_configuration do
    @bower_config = JSON.parse(IO.read("#{root}/.bowerrc"))
    sprockets.append_path File.join "#{root}", @bower_config["directory"]
end
```

In `mymain.scss`

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "susy/sass/susy";
@import "normalize.scss/normalize";
```

All of them coming from bower